# How to pull patient ID for a program/device that records MRI patient scans

Tags: hl7

My company is working on a project and we've run into a wall trying to determine the best way to pull the patients ID. We need the patients ID to name the video file for easy searching.

We want to install this system into a bunch of different scan rooms with different MRI's so we think (but we may be wrong) The best way would be to sniff from the network the conversation between the MRI and the server since this would be more standardized.

I know very little about HL7 or how MRI's interact with the server. If you have any knowledge of these protocols I would love to hear from you.

Comment: You probably want DICOM not HL7

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out in a comment - this is more related to [DICOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM), than HL7.

I assume the MRI machines will store their image data on a PACS server at some point. So the easiest way would be to just query the PACS server via its DICOM interface for MRI studies. The studies have all the patient information embedded in the DICOM image files when they are stored from the MRI to the PACS. There's also a possibility, that You could query the MRI machine itself via its DICOM interface if it happens to provide the necessary Query/Retrieve SCP-s. Information on that can be found in the DICOM conformance statement of the MRI-s. However getting the data from a PACS server would be the easiest and most logical way of achieving it.

There should be DICOM libraries available for all major programming languages and platforms both paid and free. Get one and start exploring!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a few follow up questions.

We are trying to test without our device being installed in a hospital facility, what programs would be the best to emulate a PAC server?

How would I facilitate a mock communication with this server?

Is there an online resource that would basically answer these questions? There are so many different programs and aspects to hospital info systems I don't know where to really begin. My google searches have been a little bit TOO helpful.

Comment: As I've come to understand - such questions are not welcome on this site usually, but I'll give You a few pointers. As for a light-weight PACS for testing, I think Conquest PACS server is quite easy to use. For testing the queries and sending data to the server, dcm4che toolkit could be useful. There also should be more than enough DICOM sample data on the internet (or ask Your client for some anonymized studies for testing). A specific DICOM library for Your application obviously depends on Your development language - google "my language DICOM library" or something. Also see DICOM tag on SO.

Comment: Just a tidbit to chew on, in every case that I've seen with an imaging setup - the images on the PACS system is linked up via the radiology manager via the order number, and not the patient identifier.